# "undefined columns selected" when trying to filter data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a Large Integer called `CommonIDs`. I want to filter data frame `df` by including rows where `Voter.ID` is in `CommonIDs`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df[df$Voter.ID %in% CommonIDs]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, df$Voter.ID %in% CommonIDs) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

How do I properly filter `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Correct Syntax in Base R is:

```
df[df$Voter.ID %in% CommonIDs, ]
```

In `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(Voter.ID %in% CommonIDs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`

```r
filter(df, Voter.ID %in% CommonIDs)
```